# How to connect From EMR to GCS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, amazon-emr

We have a spark streaming application running on EMR cluster, we need to store the streaming data to Google Cloud Storage in parquet format.

Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Google cloud storage (GCS) using spark on EMR, you need to include the google cloud storage connector in your application jar. You can also add the jar in hadoop classpath on EMR cluster. Quickest and easiest way is to bundle the GCS connector in your application jar.

You can get the google cloud storage connector here:

> https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage

It has connectors for hadoop 1.x, 2.x and 3.x.

Once you get the jar, add the following properties in your spark application

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true");
        sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "<path to your google cloud key>");
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("My spark application")
                .config(sparkConf)
                .getOrCreate();
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl","com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS");
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem");
```

You can put the GCP key on your EMR cluster using a simple bootstrap action script that copies the key from an s3 location to a local path.

Bundle the cloud storage connector jar with your application and now you can read/write using the "gs" filesystem.

I got this working with Hadoop 3.x and spark 3.x on EMR 6.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you process streaming data in EMR. Anyways, you can always have a custom python script using google library to connect to GCS and push your data to GCS. You can also opt to run your script as a pyspark code to quicken your process

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

This Google Cloud official guide of how to migrate from Amazon S3 to Cloud Storage may be helpful:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating

My last answer was removed, please share at least why it was deleted. Thanks.